# Crystal Reports - Two stub check detail section repeating on multiple pages

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, page-break

I have a Crystal Reports - AP Check report that is in the format Stub-Check-Stub:

- The two stubs present identical details of the check (invoices paid, etc.), with a total of invoices at the bottom of each detail section.
- The actual check is sandwiched between them in the report.

If there are more than 10 detail line items, the additional line items should appear on subsequent pages with the check section voided.

The report itself has the first stub as a subreport in the Details section within a Group by Check Number.  The check is Page Footer - A, and the second stub is a subreport in Page Footer - C.  (Page Footer - B is suppressed)

I have checked the New Page After - 10 Visible Records checkbox in the Details section of the main report, and in the Details section of both subreports.

The report works except that the second stub subreport Details section is repeating the same 10 detail lines on every page of each check.

This is essentially the same question as was asked here: [(Crystal Reports) Break page after certain # of details?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10808768/crystal-reports-break-page-after-certain-of-details) , but the answer provided didn't work for the second stub details.

Does anyone have any suggestions on this?

Answer (score 0):

The "New Page After - 10 Visible Records" will always start a new page after the 10th records.  It's similar to the solution that you provided.  If you only want 10 lines on the first page, You can use the same solution on the link but change the formula on point 5.  Only after record 10 will it start a new page.

1. Open the report in Design View
2. Right click on the Details section and select Section Expert
3. Make sure the Details section is selected in the Section Expert dialog box. Check the box that says "New Page After"
4. Click the formula editor button to the right of the checkbox.
5. Enter the following formula:

   RecordNumber = 10
6. Click Save and Close and then click OK

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  A couple of questions:Is this in the Details section of the Subreport?

Comment: ...because the Subreport in the Details section of the Main report is working properly.  My Section Expert > Paging dialog box New Page After has a checkbox by End of Section and ___ Visible Records, where a number can be entered.  Do you mean the formula next to the latter?  Is RecordNumber = 10 the only thing to enter into the formula (I receive an error: "A constant expression is required here.").  Thanks!

Comment: Opps!  Sorry, didn't realize it was a sub-report.  Put the formula in the sub-report in the section "End of Section".  You don't need to check the boxes for "End of Section" and "Visible Records".  I just tested it and it works for me.  It will print 10 lines in the sub report then continue it on the next page.  I'm not sure if the main report requires a "new page after 10" to be checked.

Comment: Thanks - is your subreport in the Details section of the main report?  I have one in the Details section, which works, and one in the Footer section, which doesn't work.  The subreport in the Footer of the main report doesn't seem to be getting the message from the main report that the page has changed.  If I open that subreport by itself, it works, but not when it is in another report.

Comment: I've recreated your issue and I see what you mean. Subreports are too finicky to work the way we want it to. They need a feature called "Can Grow". If you remove it, you will notice that if there are multiple pages because of the subreport, they disappear. An annoy part of "Can Grow" for subreport is that they take up all the space on the page. Which I understand why you are using the PF. It automatically reserves a space on the page for your check and second Subreport. But I think the PF suppresses the "Can Grow" which is why the info doesn't change. I'm trying workarounds but nothing so far.

Comment: Thanks again for looking at this.  I have tried using a group header and footer for the two stubs with the check in the details section in between...  Just as you said, if the 'Can Grow' check box is checked, the top stub takes up the whole page.  If unchecked, only the first page of records show.

Comment: Sorry, your problem stumps me.  I was trying to use a feature called "Print at Bottom of Page" in the Section Expert but still doesn't work.  Subreports are so finicky.  I can only suggest to try and get rid of the subreports and have it in the main report.  This way you have more control over the look.

Comment: Okay, thanks - I'll keep working on it.  When I finally figure something out, I'll post it here.